# FileNotFoundException on FileOutputStream in spite of mkdirs() and createNewFile()

Tags: java, file

I have a bean that download emails from SMTP server. After read emails it saves attachments on the server. To read attachment I use this code:

```
File f = new File("\\attachments\\" + attachment.getFileName());
f.mkdirs();
f.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(bytes);
fos.close();
```

I got a FileNotFoundException on FileOutputStream creating and I can't understand why.
If can help, I use NetBeans with GlassFish and the tests are made in debug in local machine.

Comment: Where do you get your `bytes` variable from. Could you please post the whole code between try/catch.

Comment: @SimonSez: that part isn't causing the exception and therefore irrelevant to the problem/question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
f.mkdirs();
```

You are creating a directory with the name of your file (that is, you create not only the directory "attachments", you also create a subdirectory with the name of your attachment filename). Then

```
f.createNewFile();
```

does not do anything since the file already exist (in the form of a directory you just created). It returns false to tell you that the file already exists.

Then this fails:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

You are trying to open an output stream on a directory. The system doesn't allow you to write in a directory, so it fails.

The bottom line is:

- `mkdirs()` doesn't do what you think it does.
- you should check the return value of your call to `createNewFile()`.

The simplest way to make it work is by replacing your line with:

```
f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

Comment: And get rid of `f.createNewFile()`, which is redundant. `new FileOutputStream()` will do it anyway, so the file created by `createNewFile()` is thrown away. Just a waste of time.